# ngRoute not working in Visual Studio 2015

Tags: visual-studio-2015, ngroute

I am trying use ngRoute to do the routing for a project I am doing in Visual Studio 2015. But as soon as I put ngRoute in angular.module, it breaks the binding with index.html page.
Does anyone know how to resolve it?

My app.js:

```
var appMainModule = angular.module('appMain', ['ngRoute']);

appMainModule.config(function ($routeProvider, $locationProvider) {
$routeProvider.when('/', {
    templateUrl: '/Templates/home.html',
    controller: 'homeViewModel'
});

    $routeProvider.otherwise({ redirectTo: '/' });
    $locationProvider.html5Mode(true);
});

appMainModule.controller("indexViewModel", function ($scope, $http, $location) {
     $scope.headingCaption = 'Angular Routing Example';
});

appMainModule.controller("homeViewModel", function($scope, $http, $location){

     $scope.headingCaption = 'This is a list of people:';

    $scope.people = [
        {firstName: 'A', lastName: 'N'}
];

$scope.showPerson = function(person){
    alert('You selected ' + person.firstName + ' ' + person.lastName);
}

});
```

My index.html:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>

<html data-ng-app="appMain" data-ng-controller="indexViewModel">
<head>
    <title></title>
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.6/css/bootstrap.min.css" integrity="sha384-1q8mTJOASx8j1Au+a5WDVnPi2lkFfwwEAa8hDDdjZlpLegxhjVME1fgjWPGmkzs7" crossorigin="anonymous">
</head>
<body>

    <h2>{{headingCaption}}</h2>
    <br />

    <div ng-view></div>

    <script src="scripts/angular.min.js"></script>
    <script src="app/app.js"></script>
    <script src="scripts/angular-route.min.js"></script>

</body>
</html>
```

When I only use: `var appMainModule = angular.module('appMain', []);` I get correct output.
index.html without ngRoute:

[image]

But when I put ngRoute and route Configuration, the page turns to this:
index.html with ngRoute:

[image: image2]

Thank you so much in advance!

Answer (score 0):

So, I solved it by removing  $locationProvider.

`appMainModule.config(function($routeProvider){
...`

Also removed:
`$locationProvider.html5Mode(true);`